# how can implemente a backgroud location service in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, location, android-jetpack-compose

i am implemente an app in jetpack compose. this app locates a device when a switch is activated. i need to build a services in background to locate it. this services must continue listening location even the app is closed. each location will be saved in firebase but it is not a problem. but i dont find any documentation to jetpack compose. all the documentation about location is to activities kotlin but not to jetpack compose.
in the mutablestate of the switch when is active i will call to function location service. but i dont know how can i impolement it.
thanks

Comment: Since background locations are in the background, I would expect any implementation to be independent of how you construct the foreground UI. "all the documentation about location is to activities" -- a Jetpack Compose UI is rendered by an activity. Compose UI replaces most of your `View` hierarchy and layout resources, but otherwise it is still Android app development, and activities are not being replaced.